# Linq: check if one of the property in a list is null for all the objects

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class P 
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public string Value {get; set;}
 public Student Student {get; set;}
}

List<P> p = new List<P>();
p.Add(new P{Name = "1", Value = null, Student = new Student{Name = "1"}})
p.Add(new P{Name = "1", Value = null, Student = new Student{Name = "1"}})        
p.Add(new P{Name = "1", Value = null, Student = new Student{Name = "1"}})
p.Add(new P{Name = "1", Value = null, Student = new Student{Name = "1"}})
p.Add(new P{Name = "2", Value = null, Student = new Student{Name = "2"}})
p.Add(new P{Name = "1", Value = "xxx", Student = new Student{Name = "2"}})
```

I want to group by **P.Name** and get only the elements which have all the missing value for P.Value.

In this example I would like to get "1"

And if I need to group for **P.Student.Name**?

Comment: I've tried both with Linq Expression and the other Linq with GroupBy and SelectMany but.. mmm

Comment: Something like p.Where(tek=>tek.Value==null).GroupBy(tek=>tek.Name)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `GroupBy` together with an `All` fro each group:

```
var r = p.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Where(g => g.All(x => x.Value == null))
    .Select(g=> g.Key);
```

**Edit:**
If you need to group by `Student.Name` you just specify that property in the `GroupBy`. You can specify any expression based on the item to be used for grouping.

```
var r = p.GroupBy(x => x.Student.Name)
    .Where(g => g.All(x => x.Value == null))
    .Select(g=> g.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I will add a second example very simlar, could you please answer that variant too?

Comment: Sure, if it similar, no problem

Comment: @Revious That sounds like it should be a new question.